# Setting property in multiple files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I recently imported a folder that contains a bunch of files into my windows forms application, these files are meant to be served as content in my application so I want to set "Copy to Output directory" property to "Copy if newer" in all files.

The problem is, the best way I found for doing this was to expand all folders in the solution explorer, select the first file, shift + select the last file, then ctrl + click all folders in the middle, and then set the property, this solution is still bad for me.

Is there a better way in Visual Studio to set a property in all files inside a project folder?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest way is to open the project file in text editor (the file with extension **.csproj**) and edit it by hand.

The file has an XML structure and will contain nodes similar to this one:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="somefile.xml">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

It might be that the `<CopyToOutputDirectory>` node is not present and the node will look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="somefile.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You can add the `<CopyToOutputDirectory>` by hand. The value inside the node can contain:

- Never - to never copy the item to the output directory
- Always - to always copy the item to the output directory
- PreserveNewest - to only copy the item to the output directory if the source item has changed

When you are done editing the file, just save it and when you switch back to Visual Studio, it will detect the change of the file and ask you to reload it.

Since it is an XML file, you can even write scripts to edit the property, if the number of files you are dealing with is large.